# Encapsulating methodes and attributes for extracted measurement from an ohmmeter in c#

Tags: c#, class, port, encapsulation

First of all i would like to apologize for my bad english. Non-native speaker. I am new to C# with only a little C/C++ experience.

I am studiying electrical engineering and doing an internship in a company producing BMS's (Battery management systems)

My task is to transfer the measurment values from an ohmmeter into my C# programm, evaluate them and save them in csv-sheet.

My device communicates via SCPI and is connetcted via usb.

I already found a example code on the Micrsofot page for port communication:

[ExampleCode for Chatprogram with SerialPort-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

After adjusting the code a bit i was able to communicate with my device.

Here is the code:

`using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class PortChat
{
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort _serialPort;

    public static void Main()
    {
        string message;
        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName); //"com9"
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One; 
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

        _serialPort.Open();
        _continue = true;
        readThread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

        while (_continue)
        {
            message = Console.ReadLine();

            if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
            {
                _continue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _serialPort.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
        readThread.Join();
        _serialPort.Close();
    }

    public static void Read()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(message);

            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }

    public static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
    {
        string portName;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
        portName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (portName == "" || !(portName.ToLower()).StartsWith("com"))
        {
            portName = defaultPortName;
        }
        return portName;
    }
}`

The ascii-values i am getting from the device are saved into the variable "message".

I would like to create an SCPI class for all the "communication with device"-functions. But i am confused because there is allready a main in here.
How can i encapsulate these functions into a class ? 
I realize that this is a very trivial question. But i am really having a hard time with object oriented programming.

Thanks in advance guys.

Greetings from Germany

*Joe*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, and you need first to do some effort by yourself. If you can't even get started, ask your teacher for help. Isolate your questions into specific programming snippets, and then search the for answers. In case you need a course or tutorial, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask it. We wish you good luck in your study. See: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).